# How to get the url before render it

Tags: python, html, django, url, view

I would like to build a system which need to detect which urls the user opened and count the opened times.

There are several different urls shared the same WaitView(TemplateView), so I want to count the numbers for each url when user click it.

I added a dic in the urls and hope it can return the correct url the user opened to the context1 in Waitview.

But I couldn't find a correct way to obtain the correct url, (I tried to use HttpRequest.get_full_path() but it continues error.
"TypeError: get_full_path() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'")

Moreover, I hope the WaitView could received the correct url and count times and then show the times on the opened page.(need the correct url before render it)

So I wander if you have some suggestions on this.

Really appreciate for your kind help.

```
# urls.py
'''
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('get_times/.+', WaitView.as_view(), {"url": ***CORRECT_URL***})
]

'''



# views.py
'''
class WaitView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'wait.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context1 = kwargs.items()
        print(context1)
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request object is stored in the `.request` attribute of a `View`. You thus can access it with `self.request` in the view methods, and you thus can obtain the url with:

```
class WaitView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'wait.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print(self.request.get_full_path())
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

You can use the [**`.build_absolute_uri()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) to generate the absolute URI (so including the protocol, hostname, etc.).

so there is no need to add a parameter to the context.

Comment: If possible, it would be really appreciate if you can answer some questions.

Comment: I am confusing what the function of the super() means here. And why when we defined the 'def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):' usually it followed with 'context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) '

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to enter in comment.

Comment: `super()` returns a proxy-object that will walk up the MRO until it finds a baseclass that defined `get_context_data`, and thus calls the one with super. We then return that result. I made a typo however, as  here we better pass `**kwargs` as well.